slope of vertical line
I have multiple lines (let's say 8 lines for this example) and I want to cluster these lines by their slopes. Therefore I calculate the slope of every line using the formula:
$m=\frac{y2−y1}{x2−x1}$
These works pretty well for most of the lines:
Image of the 8 exmaple lines with their slopes
In the image the clusters are as followed:

line 0 & line 1
line 4 & line 5
line 6 & line 7
line 2 & line 3 should also be a cluster

for clusters 1 to 3 it is pretty easy by just calculating their slopes via the formula above. If the signs of the slopes of both lines match, they are expected to have the same type of incline/decline. And if the values of the slopes lay in a threshold of 0.25 (abs(m1-m2) <= 0.25), they are clustered in one cluster.
But for cluster 4 containing line 2it was not that easy. Because of the vertical line the formula above would look like this: $m=\frac{9−1}{5−5}$ and division by 0 is not allowed, which results in no slope/infinite slope/undefined slope (?)...
How to choose a approdiate value for slope comparison for line 2 in order to still find clusters with other lines (also outside these example lines)?

If you'd rather cluster them by their angle to the real line, you can use $tan^{-1}(slope)$, which will give you something finite even for vertical lines

with "real line" do you mean the line I want to compare or using an external reference line?

I mean the horizontal real axis, y=$0$. Crudely speaking, how inclined are they from horizontal. Slope mathematically is the tan of that angle. I am just suggesting to remove the tan by using its inverse function

@Srini has the right solution. (They should post it as an answer.) You want two lines to be "close" when the angle between them is small. The slope is a very nonlinear function of the angle, so distorts your clustering.

If you plot lines with slopes $1000$ and $2000$ you will see they "cluster" much closer together than any of your lines but the $\lvert m_1 - m_2\rvert = 1000$, which is much larger than $1/4$.

two question:

Does $\tan^{-1}(slope)$ with a vertical line still result in a divison by 0?
In the image above: If line 5would be the reference line and I calculate the angles to line 5 of ´line 1and line 4` both would result in 45° even though both lines inclines are in opposite directions. How to address this?


jonsken, do you have any clustering goals? I mean do you want to figure out the number of cluster and the number of lines to cluster given a lot of lines? If so, I will post something on how to dynamically select the cluster count and resolution, given how your distribution. If not, I will simply post my comment as an answer with some illustration of the non linearity of slope. I am getting ready to leave to work, so I will post an answer tonight depending on your reply.

You don't have to divide by 0. $tan^{-1}(\infty)$ results in $\frac{\pi}{2}$. So you can simply substitute 90 degrees when you see the denominator as $0$. Answer to your other question is you will get +45 degrees or -45 degrees depending on the direction of incline

For a straight line through origin $(0,0)$,
$$y = \frac{(y2-y1)}{(x2-x1)} x  = m x$$
where m is the slope.
The relationship between the angle of incline (measured anti-clockwise from x-axis, $\color\red{\theta}$) and the slope $m$ is
$$m = tan(\theta)$$.
For your clustering purposes, if the aim is to cluster those lines that look close w.r.t. their angle of separation visually into a bunch, we should try to use the angle $\theta$ instead of the slope. $tan$ (tangent function) is very non-linear. This means that for equal jumps in $\theta$, we get unequal jumps in slope m.
The following diagram shows 4 lines, the top 2 and the bottom 2 are both separated by an angle $\frac{\pi}{16}$ (radians) within the 2, but the top 2 and bottom 2 are separtated by $\frac{\pi}{4}$ (due to which we would tend to bin them in two clusters, each containing 2 lines). But if you look at the slope $m$, they are proportional to the height of these curves at the right end of the picture (since the x-axis part is common for all of them at the right end of the picture).

The problem with this non-linearity is that you can't use the same threshold for deciding the lines that should go into each cluster.
An alternative is to simply use the angle $\theta$ to cluster. But since $\theta$ is not readily available, you can use $m$ to derive it by using the inverse tangent function.
$$\theta = tan^{-1}(m)$$
For the vertical line, you don't need to actually compute the $tan^{-1}$ (if the tool you are using does not accept infinity). You can detect when $x2-x1=0$ and simply substitute $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$.
